# How to query DynamoDB using python for date range which is stored as string?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

This is a tricky one for me, so I thought I would check here.

I have a DynamoDB table where timestamps are stored in following format as string datatype:

```
'timestamp': '2022-06-25 22:44:10.536370'
```

Now I need to be able to query this table for data with time ranges. And the time range would be something like this:

```
'from':'2021-02-17 13:00:00' 
'to': '2021-02-17 14:00:00’
```

How I can write this as a query condition in python? I am a frontend developer and only know basic SQL so I am not sure how to create this query...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you in a situation where you can change the timestamp format to ISO-8601 formatted string. If you do so, then you can store timestamp as sort key and use between operator in query.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to query DynamoDB is using the PartiQL interface, that you can read more about it here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/build-faster-with-amazon-dynamodb-and-partiql-sql-compatible-operations/

For your query on the dates you can use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2021-02-17 13:00:00' AND '2021-02-17 14:00:00'
```